# Error moving WCF service from dev machine to server

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, service

This is a WCF REST service.  The service works perfectly fine on my dev machine.

I have the service files in a subfolder of wwwroot called Services\

Admittedly I'm well versed at writing code, but no so well versed at using IIS to host/publish we services.

What I attempted to do was just copy the Services folder from my dev laptop to the server's wwwroot folder.

When this happens and I try to access the service on the server I get some strange error that I don't understand (well I sort of understand it just don't know why it's happening)

**"The type 'BooksService.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or profided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found."**

Service1.cs looks like so in my project:

```
namespace BooksService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IDataService
```

A decent portion of my web.config is based on google recommendations so it's probable I may not understand something or just have it plain wrong.

Web.Config looks like:

```
***<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="BooksService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BooksService.IDataService" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/bookservice" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>***
```

My service file looks like this:

**<% @ServiceHost Service="BooksService.Service1" %>**

Then there is a bin folder which contains my .dll

So the folder layout is as follows:

**c:\inetpub\wwwroot\SERVICES\BookService\bin**

Where service.svc is in the BookService folder and the assembly is in the bin folder.

What step(s) might I be missing?

Comment: 1. Have you confirmed that the same levels of IIS/.net etc are installed on the server? 2. Have you got any security issues? Are the same users/identities running the svc etc. These are the things to check first

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I know the service is running IIS 7.0.  Relatively sure that the dev machine is as well.

In terms of same users/identities running the svc, can you elaborate on that?  Login on my dev machine and login on the server are both admin logins.  Is there something I should be configuring in IIS to take care of this?

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking specifically of the [App Pool identities](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create an application in IIS and point the virtual directory to your application folder: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\SERVICES\BookService.

Then you need to update your service base address accordingly:

```
<baseAddresses>
     <add baseAddress="http://localhost/services/bookservice" />
 </baseAddresses>
```

You can test the url by typing it in your browser and browsing to the service location.

Comment: THANK YOU!  This was it.  So simple...I should've seen this.